# jasper studio: truncating numbers in columns

Tags: jasper-reports

[image][image]

How do you separate a number in a column (look at Publisheditemcode in the picture) where for an example 026.126572.1 becomes, as an output, 026.126572 when queried?  this is in jasper studio version 6.3 i think or the latest version of jasper studio

Comment: Do you have some troubles with data in report? I think this is just a bug of JSS

Comment: No, I don't have trouble with data in JSS.  we are pulling data from MS SQL Server 12 into JSS but I can't figure out how to separate the numbers out.  When I use truncate in JSS it says there is an error.  I use the same format as I do when I write SQL in the MS SQL Server 12 database

Comment: the second picture added is what I am trying to replicate with out adding another column in the database.  Is there a way to do this in JSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as follows:

SELECT SUBSTRING(your table name here,starting point,length) as "name",
    right(RTRIM(your table name here),length) as "name"

from "table name"

found on W3S school